# Mocking classes in Jest does not call the same method

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to mock a class that is being imported into my code with `require` and then testing if a method of that class is getting called.

I've created a sample setup where this issue can be replicated:

```js
// user.js
class User {
  getName() {
    return "Han Solo"
  }
}

module.exports = User
```

```js
// user-consumer.js
const User = require('./user')
const user = new User()

module.exports.getUserName = () => {
  // do things here
  return user.getName() 
}
```

```js
// user.test.js
const userConsumer = require('./user-consumer')
const User = require('./user')
jest.mock('./user')

it('should mock', () => {
  const user = new User()
  jest.spyOn(user, 'getName')
  userConsumer.getUserName()
  expect(user.getName).toBeCalled()
})
```

The error I get is as follows:

[image: failed test]

If I used ES6 syntax this would work as shown on jest's documentation: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks

But I unfortunately can't use ES6 on this project as it would require a lot of refactoring.

I also tried mocking the class with the module factory parameter

```js
jest.mock('./user', () => {
  return jest.fn(() => {
    return {
      getName: jest.fn(),
    }
  })
})
```

It still doesn't work. When I log `console.log(user.getName)` in `user-consumer.js:5` it does show that the method has been mocked but whatever is called in `user.getName()` is not the consumer function still returns "Han Solo".

I've also tried it with and without `jest.spyOn` and it still returns the same error.

Is this just not possible with none ES6 syntax?

Comment: You're already using ES6 syntax everywhere. If you refer to ES modules, please, be more specific. The problem is not specific to them any way.

Comment: @EstusFlask Apologies. JS isn't really my forte; I was misunderstanding the docs linked in the question. I thought ES6 syntax here already meant using `import`. What I was saying was that I tried using the import syntax in this example and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Jest spies have undocumented behaviour.

Even if prototype method is the same for all instances:

```
new User().getName === new User().getName
```

A spy is specific to an instance:

```
jest.spyOn(new User(), 'getName') !== jest.spyOn(new User(), 'getName')
```

If a specific instance is unreachable, it's a prototype that needs to be spied:

```
jest.spyOn(User.prototype, 'getName')
userConsumer.getUserName()
expect(User.prototype.getName).toBeCalled();
```

A problem with `jest.mock` isn't specific to ES6 syntax. In order for a spy to be available for assertions and implementation changes, it should be exposed somewhere. Declaring it outside `jest.mock` factory is not a good solution as it can often result in race condition described in the [manual](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmockdocsenjest-objectjestmockmodulename-factory-options-with-the-module-factory-parameter); there will be one in this case too. A more safe approach is to expose a reference as a part of module mock.

It would be more straightforward for ES module because this way class export is kept separately:

```
import MockedUser, { mockGetName } from './user';

jest.mock('./user', () => {
  const mockGetName = jest.fn();
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    mockGetName,
    default: jest.fn(() => {
      return {
        getName: mockGetName
      }
    })
  }
})
...
```

For CommonJS module with class (function) export, it will be efficiently exposed as class static method:

```
import MockedUser from './user';

jest.mock('./user', () => {
  const mockGetName = jest.fn();
  return Object.assign(
    jest.fn(() => {
      return {
        getName: mockGetName
      }
    }),
    { mockGetName }
  })
})
...
MockedUser.mockGetName.mockImplementation(...);
userConsumer.getUserName()
expect(MockedUser.mockGetName).toBeCalled();
```

Comment: Ok this makes a lot of sense. I get that I really needed to expose the mocked function reference but I was going about it the wrong way--declaring it outside of `jest.mock`. Which of course doesn't work because `jest.mock` runs before the variable gets defined.

Comment: Both using prototype and exposing the function like that works for me, do you recommend using the prototype method? I'm wondering if this affects subsequent tests that might call into this method.

Comment: Another workaround is to use `var`, which is a bit more ugly and doesn't play well with `__mocks__` any way, `var mockGetName; jest.mock('./user', () => {
  mockGetName = jest.fn() ...`. I listed both ways for completeness, because proto works well for spying/mocking prototype methods. You may need jest.mock to mock a constructor, this includes instance (arrow) methods .