# How to clear/reset mockimplementation for a method using Jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest, testcase

Using Jest I've mockimplemented the method and testcase is getting succeeded and for testcase2 I need to implement same mock method with different input and I'm unable to do that.

```
jest.mock('../../lib/testService', () => ({
  TestService : jest.fn(() => ({
      callAPIProd: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve([{ DateTime: '2022-01-01'}])),
      getAuthToken: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ data: 'mock token' })),
      checkIfExistsInDB: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(false)),
  })),
}));
```

```
describe('getRates', () => {
    it('should insert rates into DB if not already available', async () => {
      // Arrange
      const req = {} as Request;
      const res = {
        send: jest.fn(),
      } as unknown as Response;

      // Act
      await integration.getRates(req, res);

      // Assert
      expect(res.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith('New Rates Received');
    });

    it('should send response if rates are already available in DB', async () => {
      // Arrange
      const req = {} as Request;
      const res = {
        send: jest.fn(),
      } as unknown as Response;

      // Act
      await integration.getRates(req, res);

      // Assert
      expect(res.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Rates already available in DB');
    });
});
```

In my getRates method I'm calling the "checkIfExistsInDB" service method which ret=turns true/false. First testcase is getting succeeded as I've mocked the implementation with false value.
I want to clear the mockimplementation and set new mockimplementation with true value. How to achieve that?

Tried by re-defining the mock implementation in specific testcase

```
    it('should send response if rates are already available in DB', async () => {
  // Arrange
  const req = {} as Request;
  const res = {
    send: jest.fn(),
  } as unknown as Response;

  //#1 - Tried to re-define in this way but it didn't work it's still taking value as false
  jest.mock('../../lib/testService', () => ({
    TestService : jest.fn(() => ({
        callAPIProd: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve([{ DateTime: '2022-01-01'}])),
        getAuthToken: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ data: 'mock token' })),
        checkIfExistsInDB: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(true)),
    })),
  }));

  //#2 - Tried to re-define in this way but it didn't work it's still taking value as false
  TestService.prototype.checkIfExistsInDB = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(true));

  // Act
  await integration.getRates(req, res);

  // Assert
  expect(res.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Rates already available in DB');
});
```

Comment: With checkIfExistsInDB.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(true)) ? But you won't be able to reset it back to false in the same suite without explicitly writing mockImplementation

Comment: @EstusFlask - Oh, I'm not aware on this as I'm new to testcases- Thank you. Could you please let me know what do you mean by "explicitly writing mockImplementation" - How to do that?

Comment: Test cases shouldn't affect each other, and this will happen once you redefine mock value. You need checkIfExistsInDB.mockImplementation in beforeEach in addition or instead of the one inside jest.mock  if you need some default mock for the most of test cases (false). And redefine it in a specific test case (true)

Comment: I've tried redefining the mock in specific testcase but it is not working - It is taking whatever value is defined in global mock - that is why I'm asking how to redefine it?

Comment: The question doesn't contain this, can you update it with your attempt, so it could be addressed?

Comment: updated the question, can you please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jest.mock` at top level is hoisted, this is the way it affects `import` statement. `jest.mock` inside a test would result in implications, the whole module graph needs to be reimported inside a test, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58563074/3731501).

Mocking `TestService.prototype.checkIfExistsInDB` won't work because `TestService` is mocked function and doesn't deal with prototypes. In order to access `checkIfExistsInDB` in tests it needs to be exposed in the scope of test suite. Adding an import similarly to `mockGetName` in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65743420/3731501) allows to avoid possible race conditions caused by `jest.mock` hoisting:

```
import { mockedCheckIfExistsInDB  } from '../../lib/testService'

jest.mock('../../lib/testService', () => {
  const mockedCheckIfExistsInDB = jest.fn();

  return {
     __esModule: true,
     mockedCheckIfExistsInDB,
     TestService : jest.fn(() => ({
       ...
       checkIfExistsInDB: mockedCheckIfExistsInDB,
     })
  };
});

beforeEach(() => {
  mockedCheckIfExistsInDB.mockResolvedValue(false)
});

it('...', async () => {
  ...
  mockedCheckIfExistsInDB.mockResolvedValue(true)
  ...
});
```

A test that redefines `checkIfExistsInDB` mocked value shouldn't affect other tests, but this will happen if default mocked value is defined in `jest.mock`. It needs to be defined before each test instead.